# codeigniter count / with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, group-by

I have a Table `ANKETADATA` in my database which containts a column `PROVO`. I want to have output like this:

`povremeno : 15`. (The number show how many times found this row in column PRVO)
`nikad : 40`.

MODEL:

```
$anketadb = $this->load->database('anketa',TRUE);

    $anketadb->select('prvo');
    $anketadb->from('anketadata');
    $anketadb->group_by('prvo');
$result =   $anketadb->get();

$result =   $result->result_array();

$count  =   array('povremeno' => 0, 'nikad' => 0, 'svakibroj' => 0, 'prodajemkupujem' => 0);

foreach($result as $row){
    switch($row){
        case 'povremeno' :  $count['povremeno']++; break;
        case 'nikad' : $count['nikad']++; break;
        case 'svakibroj' :  $count['svakibroj']++; break;
        case 'prodajemkupujem' : $count['prodajemkupujem']++; break;
    }
}
return $count;
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$this->load->model('anketerezultati_model');
    $data['count'] = $this->anketerezultati_model->prvo();
    $this->load->view('ankete/rezultatiankete', $data);
```

VIEW:

```
echo "povremeno".$count['povremeno'];
echo "nikad".$count['nikad'];
```

The result is 0 for both. I cannot find the mistake.

Comment: I SOLVED THE PROBLEM : I put out row   $anketadb->group_by('prvo');
than it counted everything like I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this:

```
$anketadb->group_by('prvo');
```

Your foreach:

```
foreach($result as $row){
   $val = $row['prvo'];
   $count[$val]++;
}
```

Comment: Now I have for some 1 an 0.... but i have 80 rows... so i not understand how... something is wrong

Comment: I just updated my code snippet to avoid the switch statement. See how that works out.

Comment: I this way its looks like, that it will count number of all rows. Am I wrong?

Comment: I SOLVED THE PROBLEM : I put out row $anketadb->group_by('prvo'); than it counted everything like I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be faster to do this with a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`, `prvo` FROM `anketadata` GROUP BY `prvo`
```

Comment: I SOLVED THE PROBLEM : I put out row $anketadb->group_by('prvo'); than it counted everything like I wanted

Comment: It works like that yeah, but if you ever get more values in the `prvo` column, your code stop working, and if you have loads of records, it wil be alot slower then implementing the right query

Comment: In this table, I can not have another value, because there is a radio buttons in form. But thanks for advice!